# Wrong 301 redirects in .htaccess? WP site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've remade an old website `website.com` on Wordpress on my own subdomain `remake.mydomain.com` and now I would like to move it to the original domain `website.com`, but most of my URLs have changed so I'd like to make redirects to the new ones, but some of them do not redirect as expected (for me at least, because I'm a noob with the .htaccess file):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /en /
Redirect 301 /en/ /
# this works

...

Redirect 301 /en/wheel-alignment-2 /service/wheel-alignment/
Redirect 301 /en/wheel-alignment-2/ /service/wheel-alignment/
# redirects to /wheel-alignment-2 (page not found)

Redirect 301 /en/tire-mounting-2 /service/tire-mounting/
Redirect 301 /en/tire-mounting-2/ /service/tire-mounting/
# redirects to /tire-mounting-2 (page not found)

Redirect 301 /en/news--sales /news-and-sales/
Redirect 301 /en/news--sales/ /news-and-sales/
# redirects to /news--sales (page not found)

...

Redirect 301 /en/testimonials /
Redirect 301 /en/testimonials/ /
# this is the last redirect, redirects to /testimonials (page not found)
```

One even redirected to an image in /wp-content/, but I found out that Yoast SEO was causing this, so turned off "Media & attachment URLs" in "Search Appearance" > "Media" and it worked normally.

By the way, as you can see, the old site had language extension in the URL and I don't need it anymore.

The end result should be like this:

```
website.com/en > website.com
website.com/en/wheel-alignment-2 > website.com/service/wheel-alignment
website.com/en/news--sales > website.com/news-and-sales
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what's wrong and how to do this correctly if I'm doing it wrong?

As I've said earlier I'm a noob with .htaccess and probably should use redirect conditions and rules, but as much as I google, I just can't grasp the concepts and haven't found any simple explanations for how it all works.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your htaccess file in your question. Could you please also do mention FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite? for better understanding of your question, kindly update your question.

Comment: Hello and thank you, the URL will not change, as a final result it will stay the same, I just made a subdomain on my own domain to create the new site and after I'll migrate to the original. I've updated my question, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

If I get it correctly you want to redirect to website.com from old domain, if this is the case then add following to very top of your .htaccess file and keep the rest of your rules as it is.

Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Redirect from remake.mydomain.com TO website.com here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} remake\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

##Redirecting from website.com/en TO website.com
RewriteRule ^en/?$ / [NC,R=301,L]

##Redirecting from website.com/en/wheel-alignment-2 TO website.com/service/wheel-alignment
RewriteRule ^en/wheel-alignment-2/?$ service/wheel-alignment [NC,R=301,L]

##Redirecting from website.com/en/news--sales TO website.com/news-and-sales
RewriteRule ^en/news--sales/?$ news-and-sales [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I doubt there should be any mention of my development subdomain, because the site will remain `website.com` after I move it. Will `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website\.com [NC]
` work? Thank you.

Comment: @Adam, but you have mentioned like `Wordpress on my own subdomain remake.mydomain.com and now I would like to move it to the original domain website.com` could you please do mention in more details whichever links you want to redirect.

Comment: Sorry, I'd like the redirects to be like this: `website.com/en` > `website.com`, `website.com/en/wheel-alignment-2` > `website.com/service/wheel-alignment`, `website.com/en/news--sales` > `website.com/news-and-sales` and so on. I'm doing this for SEO purposes.

Comment: @Adam, so your redirect is not working or giving any errors?

Comment: Like I wrote in my question it redirects it in a wrong way, and when I tried your answer it wrote `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: @Adam, so basically you want to remove `en` like from link `http://localhost:80/en/singh_test` TO `http://localhost:80/singh_test` OR any other rules are there also?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and many paths have also changed, like for example: `news--sales` to `news-and-sales`.

Comment: @Adam, Could you please check my edited rules and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: I've removed all of my redirects (except wp defaults) and put yours, when I put this in:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} remake\.mydomain\.com [NC]`, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]`
Then it redirects from remake.mydomain.com to website.com, but all others don't work. Isn't it strange? To me it looks ok, could it be that wp defaults are somehow causing this?

Comment: @Adam, could you please do let me know what error are you getting? I am not having wp with me but I tested these with htaccess in my local and it looks ok to me, let me know more details and we could troubleshoot more on this one, cheers.

Comment: How should I debug? Never done this before. It just opens "page not found", no errors.

Comment: @Adam, if you have `curl` utility with you then you could use command like `curl -IL "http://localhost:80/test_bla_your_url"` and this will show better error. If you don't have `curl` you could download its binary too.

Comment: I gave up, just found and installed a plugin called Redirection and it does the job. Tried curl command to check the statuses and only got 404. No idea why redirects using RewriteRule do not work, while Redirect 301 work, although not as expected. Tried exporting the rules from Redirection and putting them in .htaccess and they don't work there either. No clues. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Adam, thanks for sharing info, could you please do let me know if curl gives you any additional info here?